Why does Vec not support zero-copy?
Why is it that dynamic types cannot support zero-copy / lazy loading? Under normal circumstances where data is stored on the heap and not serially, i'd understand. But doesn't Vec use the solana account storage which contains contiguous data and therefore should support LL? am i missing something?

The problem is that Vecs are typically dynamically allocated. If it grows beyond a certain amount, the Vec will reallocate itself to contain more and copy the old data into the new buffer. This model does not work cleanly with Solana accounts, where reallocation must be done from the outside.
With that said, you can safely get a read-only version of a Vec in a Solana program. Most use Borsh encoding, which means that the length of the vector is stored in 4 bytes, followed by the actual data, which will take up len * size_of::<T> bytes. So you can transmute those bytes into [T].
For writing, it's also possible, but a bit trickier -- you can overallocate the account, and then figure out your current length and total possible capacity separately. The SPL PodSlice shows how this can be done: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/libraries/pod/src/slice.rs
